# Bootstrap Popover data read twice by JAWS screen reader

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, screen-readers, jaws-screen-reader

We are using Bootstrap Pop Over widget for showing the data on hover and focus of the link.
This link, we are adding into Table which is created by using the Data Tables.

Currently, we are facing the issue with Accessibility Compliance. We are using JAWS tool for screen reading.

When the focus goes to that pop over link it gets shown but JAWS reads it twice.

Not sure why it is doing like it. Is it due to we are using that in table?
On other places it works perfectly only difference is it is not rendered in table?

Thanks for help.